# Find the biggest Contour- OpenCV, Python - Getting Errors

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour

I am trying to find the biggest contour around a car in an image. 
To find the contour I have learnt the following from the official OpenCv documentation:

```
 #convert the image to grayscale from rgb 
 1. image_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
 2. threshold  = cv2.threshold(image_gray, 127,(0,255,0),0)
 3. image2, contours_list, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(threshold, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APROX_SIMPLE)
```

problem -1: 
 
I have already applied cv2.GaussianBlur() and converted it to HSV format to create masks to detect some specific color later using MorphologyEx methods. The Problem is, the code in step 2 above requires the image either in RGB format to convert it to Gray scale or the Gray format itself but I have HSV format for which there's no such flag as cv2.COLOR_HSV2GRAY.

I have written the following 2 versions of the same method to find the biggest contour and they are throwing 2 different errors: 
In this method, I am first creating a threshold, which requires a GRAY scale image, to pass to the cv2.findContour method

```
def find_biggest_contour(image):
   image = image.copy() 
   #1
   image_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
   #2 
   threshold = cv2.threshold(image_gray,127, 255,0)
   #3
   image2, contours, heirarchy = cv2.findContours(threshold, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) # countours is a python list
   contours_sizes= [(cv2.contourArea(cnt), cnt) for cnt in contours]
   biggest_contour = max(contours_sizes, key=lambda x: x[0])[1]
   #define a mask
   mask = np.zeros(image.shape, np.uint8)
   cv2.drawContours(mask,[biggest_contour], -1, (0,255,0), 3)# 3=thickness, -1= draw all contours, 2nd arg must be a list 
   return biggest_contour, mask
```

this method is throwing me the following error:
[image: error for the 1st version of method]
The other version is as follows(basically, I have taken it from somewhere):

```
def find_biggest_contour(image):
   image = image.copy()
   im2,contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(image, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

   contour_sizes = [(cv2.contourArea(contour), contour) for contour in contours]
   biggest_contour = max(contour_sizes, key=lambda x: x[0])[1]

   mask = np.zeros(image.shape, np.uint8)
   cv2.drawContours(mask, [biggest_contour], -1, 255, -1)
   return biggest_contour, mask
```

This method throws the following error:
[image: error for the 2nd version of method]

Kindly help me fix the errors. I am new to opencv.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From OpenCV 4.0, `findContours()` return only 2 values, so it should be:

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(threshold, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Answer (score 3):

I dont know exactly, what is causing you the problem, but I bet it was caused by this

```
threshold = cv2.threshold(image_gray,127, 255,0)
```

this function

```
cv2.threshold()
```

returns **tuple**, so you need to unpack more vals. like this

```
_,threshold = cv2.threshold(image_gray,127, 255,0)
```

where **_** ignores the first returned value of the tuple

and where **threshold** is the matrix.

so basicly what we did is this:

```
_, matrix = (127,'Matrix')
>>> print(matrix)
'Matrix'
```

What you did is this:

```
matrix = (127,'Matrix')
>>> print(matrix)
(127,'Matrix')
```

**Complete code: works for me**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

hsv_image = cv2.imread('someimage.jpg',1) # pretend its HSV
rgbimg = cv2.cvtColor(hsv_image, cv2.COLOR_HSV2RGB)
image_gray = cv2.cvtColor(rgbimg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_,threshold = cv2.threshold(image_gray,127, 255,0)

im2,contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(threshold, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contour_sizes = [(cv2.contourArea(contour), contour) for contour in contours]

biggest_contour = max(contour_sizes, key=lambda x: x[0])[1]
```

**Note to mention:**

Its important to understand, that OpenCV from some reason(I heard from historical one) is not using RGB, but BGR color space. As long as you work with grayscale or only inside opencv (without using RGB), you will not even know. But once you transform yout array into PIL, you will know... One more note. In your case its ok, because BGR to GRAY or RGB to GRAY results in the same image...

Comment: that information was valuable but didn't fix the error. thanks.

Comment: I am afraid the maximum cnt is the whole img, you need to filter those objs...